# Understanding Gradle build scripts

Tags: android, gradle

I'm new in Gradle so maybe this is a silly question. I'm trying to add my Maven repository to download dependencies from Gradle, but I'm a little confused.

Project module is the root one and app module is the only subproject.

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                credentials {
                    username 'xxxxxx'
                    password 'xxxxxx'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**build.gradle (App module)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            credentials {
                username 'xxxxx'
                password 'xxxxx'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        //more dependencies from mavenCentral()
        classpath 'my.group.id:my-artifact:1.0.0' //<--- this dependency is from my repository
    }
}


    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        //more dependencies

        compile 'my.group.id:my-artifact:1.0.0' //<--- this dependency is from my repository

    }
```

Have I to put my repository's configuration in both files? Why? I mean, I have already put it in `allprojects` in project's `build.gradle`. How can I reference my repository in app module's `build.project` without put its configuration again?

Can I put this information in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file?

I want to understand how configure it correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your App is your root project?  Is that what you mean? then the project is the subprojects?  If that's the case you can put everything in allprojects configuration and you can put the your credentials in the gradle.properties and flop the property names here for user and password.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            credentials {
                username 'xxxxx'
                password 'xxxxx'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The other way around. Project is the root. If the repository definition is not in the app `build.gradle`, am I able to declare (`classpath`) dependencies?

Comment: Dependencies depends on whether you have that in your repository, in this case mavencentral.  The classpath line is for your buildscript.  When you say classpath .... you're telling gradle that it needs this library to run build script.  When you say compile .... you're telling gradle to pull that library from repository and use it for compilation.  Short answer is you should be able to because gradle would know where to grab it based on your repository statement.